# pre fill registration form

Tags: php, html

I have a registration form on my website and I want certain fields to be pre-filled when a user returns.  for example first name, last name, job function etc but other fields to be left blank that are unique to the particular registration process.

what options do I have to do this for example user log in, "remember me"....etc ?

Also what are the pros and cons of these possible options(breifley)

any help would be great

Comment: Pre-filling a registration form with data from a former visitor, does imply that visitor didn't finish the registration process on his last visit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question totally but maybe this will help:

a.) Store the pre register data in a database. Then when the user returns, just select the pre filled data from the db and then just display it as you like.

b.) Use `$_SESSION` in PHP.

[as I said, I don't know what you want to do...]

Answer (score 0):

store the form data in the database and maybe compare user id with table id of the form table.

and something like that:

```
<input value="LOAD_DB_FIELD">
```